# Active Compilation Conditions not working

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to use an Active Compilation Condition to check if I have to activate a feature or not. However, the code inside the if statement is never getting called, even if I force the compilation condition to all of my schemes. There's something I could be missing here?

```
#if ENABLE_CERTIFICATE_PINNING
// This is never getting called
let evaluator = PinnedCertificatesTrustEvaluator()
let serverTrustManager = ServerTrustManager(evaluators: ["...": evaluator])
let session = Session(interceptor: interceptor, serverTrustManager: serverTrustManager)
#else
// This is called always
let session = Session(interceptor: interceptor)
#endif
```

[image: __]

[image: __]

Comment: make sure you're running the target where you've added the flag.

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue. Did you ever find a solution?